# Block cipher information leakage using same key

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, des, information-theory

This is from a previous exam question and I'm not really sure how to approach this properly

> We're using a block-cipher mode that encrypts
>
> $C_i$ = $E_k$ ($P_i$ $\oplus$ $C_{i-1}$ $\oplus$ $P_{i-1}$) with $C_0$
>   = IV and $P_0$ = 0.
>
> Indicate whether information leaks on the plaintext if too many
>   plaintext blocks are encrypted under the same key (use as example
>   DES).

Now I'm not really sure how to indicate this. But I assumed that if the IV is truly random that no leakage should happen.

My opinion even if you do a chosen-plaintext attack where $P_1$ = 0

$C_1$ = $E_k$ ($P_1$ $\oplus$ $IV$ $\oplus$ $P_0$) = $E_k$ ($0$ $\oplus$ $IV$ $\oplus$ $0$) which would give $C_1$ = $E_k$ ($IV$)

$C_2$ = $E_k$ ($P_2$ $\oplus$ $C_1$ $\oplus$ $P_1$) = $E_k$ ($P_2$ $\oplus$ $E_k$ ($IV$) $\oplus$ $0$)

$...$

I don't see how it would leak any information on the plaintext. I might be assessing the question wrong though.

Comment: Maybe this is going for a collision attack like Sweet32?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the 'birthday bound' in block ciphers are collisions that may occur after an expected $2^{n/2}$ blocks (or lack there-of); cases where the inputs to the block cipher is exactly the same (and hence the output is as well).

How might someone, with a large amount of ciphertext, find such collisions in the mode in question?  Having found such a collision, how might they use it to deduce information about the plaintext?

Comment: I always find the combination of "expected collisions" and $2^{n/2}$ rather wanting.  It sounds all or nothing.  A 50%  probability of collision is in security terms virtually 100%.  NIST recognises this asymptotic distribution with their block/byte count recommendations, and true expected collision probabilities in terms of security levels.  I can't find (on this forum) where this has been rigorously dealt with. Just a €'s worth...